# Overloading operator += with two classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I have two classes, lets call them `A` and `B`. And I overloaded `operator+=` in class `A`. Now I want to do something like this:

```
A += B + B + B
```

And class `B` doesn't have overloaded `operator+`, which is a problem because the evaluation is right to left (it wants to add all `B`s and then += the result to `A`).
Is there any way to achieve my goal without actually overloading `operator+` for class `B`?

Comment: `A += B; A += B; A += B;`?

Comment: Needing to not overload `operator+` seems like an arbitrary restriction. I recommend that you consider whether that's actually important.

Comment: `+=` is right-to-left associative, so you can't do something like `A += B += B += B`, as it's parsed as `A += (B += (B += B))`, but if you were writing something like iostreams, `<<` is left-to-right associative, so you could write `A << B << B << B`

Comment: Can you do `((A += B) += B) += B`?

Comment: I can’t really modify the transcription. So only way to deal with this is to implement the operator+ for the class B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve my goal without actually overloading `operator+` for class `B`?

In a word, **no**.

`A::operator+=` takes a `B` as input, so if you want `A += B + B + B to work`, you need a way of adding `B` objects together to produce a new `B` that `+=` can take as input, and that is exactly what `operator+` is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

Instead of overloading the addition operator, you can make `B` implicitly convertible to and from an arithmetic type. A demo that requires no overloading of `operator+` for `B` as per requirement, yet allows the exact expression that you desire:

```
struct B {
    B() = default;

    // this constructor makes B convertible from int
    B(int){}

    // this operator makes B convertible to int
    operator int() {
        return 42;
    }
};


struct A {
    A& operator+=(const B&) {
        return *this;
    }

    // alternative:
    // if you use this, then B does not need to convert from int
    // A& operator+=(int)
};

int main() {
    A A;
    B B;
    A += B + B + B;
}
```